# Newbie Python project: Transforming strings into colored squares (like a cubist painting)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a language teacher and green newbie to Python. I'm trying to write a program that converts text input into series of colored boxes. The end result should be something that looks a bit like a cubist painting. (The idea is to turn boring grammar and vocabulary into colorful patterns to motivate students.)

It's my first attempt to work with GUI and so far I haven't a real clue where to look for tutorials that help me realize the following:

1) Automatically assigning a different color to each letter of the alphabet (with the assignment open for later modification)
2) Display the assignment of all color-letter pairings so that the user which color means which.
3) Transform an input into chains of brightly colored squares.

As for the code, I've only come up with the following sketch before finding myself in a blind alley:

```
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()
b = 600
h = 400
w = Canvas(master, 
       width=b,
       height=h)
w.pack()

# START POSITION
X = 1
Y = 1

# Width and height of the colored squares
width = 50
height = 50

w.create_rectangle(1, 1, 50, 50, fill="yellow")
w.create_rectangle(60, 1, 110, 50, fill="red")
```

I don't want to ask for free code, but maybe a pointer or two where I have to look for answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately SO is not a place to learn. You have to find other sources. There are quite a lot python tutorials on YT and elsewhere. Google for "python gui" to find the right libs. QT is a simple framework which you can use, I guess. Once you're stuck with coding problems, come back. Good luck.

Comment: To generate evenly distributed colors, I like to rotate around hue in color-space, using https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to assign colors randomly. You could make a list of colors you like, and then use a random number to select an entry from that list, or you could just generate random RGB values for truly random colors (http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/colors.html). Also, Python's `ord()` method is useful for turning characters into numbers, if that's something you find you can make use of.

If you want to display and modify pairings, you could use a dictionary, e.g.:

```
{'a':"red", 'b':"blue", ... }
```

Then, to line up your rectangles, just use a loop and increment your coordinates each time. The modulo operator (`%`) could be used to help you wrap around onto each new row.